# touch negative and positive side of battery briefly

Tags: batteries, short-circuit

I on accident made a brief connection between the positive and negative size of a 3.7v battery.  Connection was for less than half a second but I saw small amount of smoke come out from the wire.  Can I still use this battery and is there damage?

link of battery 
[https://www.amazon.com/Samsung-INR18650-35E-Rechargeable-BD-Electronics/dp/B0762M1WDD/ref=sr_1_19_a_it?ie=UTF8&qid=1536353635&sr=8-19&keywords=inr18650](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0762M1WDD)

Comment: If the smoke was from the spark between the contacts and the time period was as short as you think, the battery is probably fine.  You could use a separate lithium ion charger to charge it and discharge it separate from a device to be sure.

Comment: 3.7v probably means Lithium Ion, which are notoriously dangerous (as in they like to catch fire). If I were you I'd keep using it, but not for anything where it'll be unattended, just on the off chance it does decide to catch fire (which is the worst case scenario, you can search for YouTube videos of that happening).

Answer (score 2):

Normal battery packs have BMS circuit to protect it from short circuit and overdraining. You said the smoke came from the wire, which is mostly the result of the wires being overheated due to the short circuit current. Check your battery with a multimeter to see if you still get normal readings, most likely the battery should still work if the BMS circuit inside didn't get damaged.

You added links of your battery, and that battery doesn't come with any BMS so there's chances that you might damage the cells due to the high discharge current during short circuit. 
If this is for personal project you can monitor if the battery is discharging at normal rate or if it's drained faster than usual to determine the state of the battery.

[Battery datasheet](https://www.orbtronic.com/content/samsung-35e-datasheet-inr18650-35e.pdf)